# The paper behind an olympiad problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

In IMO Shortlist 2013, there is a number theory problem:

Determine whether there exists an infinite sequence of nonzero digits $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ and a positive integer $N$ such that for every integer $k>N$, the number $\overline{a_ka_{k-1}...a_1}=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i10^{i-1}$ is a perfect square.

This is a very interesting problem and the generalizations of this problem can have research value. So I guess that this problem is based on some research paper.

> Is there any paper about or relates to this problem?

Comment: I assume the notation $\overline{a_ka_{k-1}...a_1}$ means the number $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i10^{i-1}$.

Comment: @YCor I would assume that it means the repeating decimal, i.e. $(1-10^{-k})^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^ka_i10^{1-i}$, and that the OP wants to be a square in $\mathbb{Q}$.  But it would be best for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @NeilStrickland I think YCor's interpretation is correct. The overline notation is pretty standard in olympiad circles to denote the number represented by a decimal string.

Answer (score 8):

This problem and its solution appeared in a 1981 issue of [Crux Mathematicorum](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=7&issue=9), volume 7, issue 9, pages 280-282.

There it was proven by L. Csirmaz that the longest possible sequence is $25, 625, 5625, 75625,275625$.

The problem was first posed by K.S. Williams in 1980. I copy below  the results from an initial computer search, which was then shown to be exhaustive in 1981.

[image]

[[source]](https://cms.math.ca/wp-content/uploads/crux-pdfs/Crux_v7n03_Mar.pdf)

A variety of proofs can be found at [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h597246p3544103).

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A288854